How to disable copy paste and cut in excel but only specific column For ex. A1 - A100
Sub KorumaAyari()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngUnprotected As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Çalışma sayfasını belirle
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sayfa1") ' Sayfa1'ı kendi sayfa adınıza göre değiştirin
    
    ' Tüm sütunları koruma altına al
    ws.Protect
    
    ' ABCDE sütunlarını korumasız yap
    Set rngUnprotected = ws.Range("A:E")
    rngUnprotected.Locked = False
    
    ' Kilitlenmiş hücreleri yeniden koruma altına al
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
        If cell.Locked = True Then
            cell.Worksheet.Protect Password:="şifre", AllowFormattingCells:=True
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Kopyalama işlemlerini engelle
    ws.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
End Sub


You are trying to change the sheet after you have protected it. Try changing your code to something like this
Sub KorumaAyari()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' set worksheet & range to protect
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sayfa1") 
    Dim rngProtected As Range
    Set rngProtected = ws.Range("A1:A100")

    ' In case this is a re-run
    ws.Unprotect Password:="sifre"
    
    'Lock down only the cells we're concerned about
    ws.Cells.Locked = False
    rngProtected.Locked = True
    ws.Protect Password:="sifre", AllowFormattingCells:=True
    
    'Prevent the locked cells being selected (and therefore copied)
    ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

End Sub

